# Build and run ASP.NET Core WebAPI using dotnet CLI

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, dotnet-cli

I am trying to compile and run a clean ASP.NET Core WebAPI using the dotnet CLI, using both *Windows* and *OS X*.

What I´ve tried..

1. Created new ASP.NET 5 WebAPI using (Yeoman with generator-aspnet, or Visual Studio - I tried both)
2. dotnet restore, dotnet build (build fails...)

   **Project WebApiCoreT (DNXCore,Version=v5.0) will be compiled because some of its inputs were newer than its oldest output.
   Compiling WebApiCoreT for DNXCore,Version=v5.0
   C:\Data\Code\WebApiCore\WebApiCoreT\project.json(9,29): error NU1002: The dependency Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common 1.1.0-rc1-20151109-01 does not support framework DNXCore,Version=v5.0.
   C:\Data\Code\WebApiCore\WebApiCoreT\project.json(9,29): error NU1002: The dependency Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp 1.1.0-rc1-20151109-01 does not support framework DNXCore,Version=v5.0.**

   Compilation failed.
       0 Warning(s)
       2 Error(s)

   Time elapsed 00:00:01.2486558
3. dnu restore, dotnet build, dotnet run (build successful, fails at runtime...)

   Project WebApiCoreT (DNXCore,Version=v5.0) will be compiled because some of its inputs were newer than its oldest output.
   Compiling WebApiCoreT for DNXCore,Version=v5.0

   Compilation succeeded.
       0 Warning(s)
       0 Error(s)

   Time elapsed 00:00:01.2756028

   **Could not resolve coreclr path**

As far as I have understood, the dnu, dnx, dnvm toolchain is deprecated and will eventually disappear, but how can I create a WebAPI using the dotnet CLI?

Is there anyway to build anything using the dotnet CLI except for the default "Hello world!" console application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not be able to compile (yet) the application generated by yeoman with the CLI because it generates RC1 (dnx) project templates and references.

Use the [MusicStore sample](https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/tree/dev/src/MusicStore) as a template for how a dotnet web app should look like.